# Authlogic 3.0.4 doesn't find current_user for POST in Rails 4.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, ruby-on-rails-4, authlogic

When testing the latest release of Authlogic 3.4.0 my application works perfect with `GET` requests it finds and sets the current user properly. When performing a `POST` request to the server `current_user` is not being set it only returns nil

Currently using Rails 4.0.3 and Ruby 2.1.0-rc1. Also tested with Ruby 2.1.1 and received the same result. I'm sure all my controllers are configured properly because we have been using Authlogic
for some time now in our Rails 3 app. I am currently upgrading the app to run on Rails 4 and the login process works perfectly and keeps the `current_user`. All `GET` api requests made to the server will retrieve the `current_user` properly. But for some reason when I make a `POST` request it returns `nil`

Any ideas? I have also posted in the Authlogic issues on github but since the project is not very active currently I don't know if I'll ever get a reply on that thread so thought I would try here as well.